# Blender to Godot: Export as glTF without materials, but with empty material slots

Tags: materials, export, gltf

I want to export objects that have multiple materials, without exporting the actual materials, since I'm making materials in Godot.

Disabling Geometry > Materials in the exporter makes it not export materials, but then I end up with only 1 material slot, when the meshes have faces assigned to multiple materials. I also tried having emptying the material slots in Blender, but that also makes them be exported with only 1 slot.

For example, I have this mesh:

[image: tv mesh]

It has 4 material slots:

[image: materials in blender]

The materials currently loaded in those slots are basic materials I make with only a color texture, just to help me UV map the meshes. I make the "real" materials in Godot, so I don't need to export them.

After importing to Godot, I load the real materials:

[image: materials in godot]

This is with Geometry > Materials enabled. With it disabled, or with empty slots in Blender, I only get 1 slot, with all faces assigned to it:

[image: 1 slot in godot]

Apparently it's added automatically by Godot, since this glTF file has no `materials` node, unlike the one exported with materials.

This is the `materials` node in the glTF with materials exported:

```
"materials" : [
    {
        "doubleSided" : true,
        "emissiveFactor" : [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "name" : "plastic_black",
        "pbrMetallicRoughness" : {
            "baseColorTexture" : {
                "index" : 0,
                "texCoord" : 0
            },
            "metallicFactor" : 0,
            "roughnessFactor" : 0.5
        }
    },
    {
        "doubleSided" : true,
        "emissiveFactor" : [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "name" : "chrome",
        "pbrMetallicRoughness" : {
            "baseColorFactor" : [
                0.800000011920929,
                0.800000011920929,
                0.800000011920929,
                1
            ],
            "metallicFactor" : 1,
            "roughnessFactor" : 0.0416666679084301
        }
    },
    {
        "doubleSided" : true,
        "emissiveFactor" : [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "name" : "wood",
        "pbrMetallicRoughness" : {
            "baseColorTexture" : {
                "index" : 1,
                "texCoord" : 0
            },
            "metallicFactor" : 0,
            "roughnessFactor" : 0.5
        }
    },
    {
        "doubleSided" : true,
        "emissiveFactor" : [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "name" : "screen_padding",
        "pbrMetallicRoughness" : {
            "baseColorFactor" : [
                0,
                0,
                0,
                1
            ],
            "metallicFactor" : 0,
            "roughnessFactor" : 0.5
        }
    },
    {
        "doubleSided" : true,
        "emissiveFactor" : [
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "name" : "screen",
        "pbrMetallicRoughness" : {
            "baseColorFactor" : [
                0.800000011920929,
                0.800000011920929,
                0.800000011920929,
                1
            ],
            "metallicFactor" : 0,
            "roughnessFactor" : 0.5
        }
    }
],
```

Changing it to this

```
"materials" : [
{},
{},
{},
{},
{}
],
```

does remove the materials and leave empty slots. Can I make it do this automatically? Also, Blender still exports textures, so I'll have to manually delete them every time as well.

Comment: This seems like a feature request for the addon, https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO.